# Prove that $\|x\|_A$ is a vector norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Prove: A is a positive definite symmetric matrix and

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R^n}$ define $||x||_A$ by $||x||_A=\sqrt{x^TAx}$

Show $||x||_A$ is a vector norm.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to prove. As far as I know, something is a vector norm if it satisfies the three axioms of a norm, and the term "vector" is used to contrast "matrix norm".

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it is **not** necessarily true that $||x||_A=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2}=\sqrt{x^Tx}$ must be satisfied (and in general it won't be for a positive definite $A$).  Also, I have no idea what you could possibly mean by "choose $Ax = x$".

**Hint:** Note that there must exist an invertible matrix $U$ such that $\|x\|_A^2 = (Ux)^T(Ux)$.  Now, it'll be easy to show that this function satisfies the requirements of a norm.